# C# cut diagonally rectangle out of a bitmap

Tags: c#, image, graphics, crop, diagonal

is there a way to crop a rectangular out of a bitmap?
The new image section lies obliquely in the original image.

I know the way how to do this using a starting point, width and height.
But is there a way to do this using two diagonal points?

Any ideas?

Comment: What would be the difference?? The 2nd point is width and height away from the first! Use this handy function: `static public Rectangle GetRectangle(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return new Rectangle(Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X), Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y),
        Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y));
}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. That seems easy :) Tomorrow I will test it.